# Parse Cloud Code Get User Who Made The Request

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

In Parse Cloud code I can get the user object making a request by the following:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getSomeData", function(request, response) {
var user = request.user;
console.log(user);
}
```

This will log out something similar to the following:

```
ParseUser { _objCount: 0, className: '_User', id: 'h5W8zz9O8u' }
```

However, I am unable to pull out the id by using:

```
user.get("id");
```

I get a return of undefined. Any advice on what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var user = request.user;
console.log(user.id);
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Thanks, using dot notation was a lot more elegant than my approach. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
In parse cloud code use:

Parse.Cloud.define("user", function(request, response) {
var id = request.params.id;  // id is parameter
console.log(id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What it turns out is I was pulling the value out incorrectly.

Instead of using:

```
user.get("id");
```

I should have been treating it as a standard object and using:

```
user["id"];
```